# How to override exception messages in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django class based view and rest framework

```
object = self.get_object()
```

In Detail view if object does not exist and i do get request like

```
/user/10
```

then i get this response

```
{"detail": "not found"}
```

Now i want to customize that response

like

```
try:
   obj = self.get_object()
except:
   raise Exception("This object does not exist")
```

But thats not working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can **implement a [custom exception handler function](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)** that returns the custom response in case the object does not exist.

In case a object does not exist, `Http404` exception is raised. So, we will check if the exception raised is `Http404` and if that is the case, we will return our custom exception message in the response.

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from django.http import Http404

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if isinstance(exc, Http404):  
        custom_response_data = { 
            'detail': 'This object does not exist.' # custom exception message
        }
        response.data = custom_response_data # set the custom response data on response object

    return response
```

After defining our custom exception handler, we need to add this custom exception handler to our DRF settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Comment: The exception is sailed within get_object() method of DRF .  i think DRF has its own try except block there .  is there any way that if i use try case on the top of that , like in my example , then my exception gets raised rather than DRF .

Comment: Yes, a `Http404` exception does get raised in the `get_object` method of DRF. You can use the method given in the ans and that should give you the same exception message in the response as you want. Just in case you want to override the `get_object` function, you can do that in your view by overriding the function.

Comment: @RahulGupta Import Error: Could not import 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler' for API setting 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER'. AttributeError: module my_project.my_app.utils' has no attribute 'custom_exception_handler'. 

Could not solve it, please help

Comment: This example assumes that you have created an `utils.py` file inside `my_app` for `my_project`. Inside the `utils.py` file, you need to define your function. Please check if you have done the same.

Comment: @EngineSense the import issue will come always because you don't have create __init__.py file in utils folder and you import it in your settings.py file, must have __init__.py file in utils folder.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a custom exception class as below, and it would raise **APIException** with a `custom message` and `custom status_code`

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
from rest_framework import status



class CustomAPIException(ValidationError):
    """
    raises API exceptions with custom messages and custom status codes
    """
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_code = 'error'

    def __init__(self, detail, status_code=None):
        self.detail = detail
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
```

and in your `views`,

```
from rest_framework import status

try:
    obj = self.get_object()
except:
    raise CustomAPIException("This object does not exist", status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

The response will be like this 
`{"detail": "This object does not exist"}`

### NOTE

the `detail` parameter of `CustomAPIException` class takes `str`,`list` and `dict` objects. If you provide a `dict` object, then it will return that dict as exception response

### UPDATE

As [@pratibha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469207/pratibha) mentioned, it's not possible to produce desired output if we use this exception class in Serializer's `validate()` or `validate_xxfieldName()` methods.
**Why this behaviour ?**
I wrote a similar answer in SO, here [Django REST Framework ValidationError always returns 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566095/django-rest-framework-validationerror-always-returns-400)

**How to obtain desired output within the serializer's `validate()` method?**
Inherit **`CustomAPIException`** from **`rest_framework.exceptions.APIException`** instead of from `rest_framework.serializers.ValidationError`
ie,

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException


class CustomAPIException(APIException):
    # .... code
```

Comment: This is not working, I am getting `{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "This object does not exist"
    ]
}`

Comment: Where did you raised the exception ? serializer? or in view?

Comment: It's not mandatory. You got that kind of error because of this , [Django REST Framework ValidationError always returns 400](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567740/8283848)

Comment: @pratibha I've updated the answer. Now it's possible

Comment: is it possible to add more keys in that JSON?

Comment: Yeah, It's possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179952/discussion-between-pratibha-and-jpg).