# Django REST Framework ValidationError always returns 400

Tags: django-rest-framework, http-status-codes, serialization

I am trying to force `ValidationError` to return a different status code than 400. This is what I did:

```
class MyValidationError(ValidationError):
    status_code = HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
```

and then in a serializer:

```
def validate_field(self, value):
    raise MyValidationError
```

Why do I get 400 here instead of 403? An interesting thing is that if I use `PermissionDenied` with a custom status code (I tried 204) instead of `ValidationError`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Django RestFramework serializer validates all possible fields and finally returns *set of errors*.
That is, suppose you are expecting two validation errors in serializer, in that one validation error is raised by `MyValidationError`. In that case DRF obviously return `HTTP 400` status code, because the **design patterns** of DRF not raising **individual** validation errors.

The serializer validation process done inside the [`is_valid()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L221) method and it raises ValidationError at the end of the method.

```
def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
    ....code
    ....code
    if self._errors and raise_exception:
        raise ValidationError(self.errors)

    return not bool(self._errors)
```

and the [`ValidationError`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L142) class raises `HTTP 400`

```
class ValidationError(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_detail = _('Invalid input.')
    default_code = 'invalid'
    .... code
```

**Why PermissionDenaid returns custom status code?**

In the [`is_valid()` (source code)](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L234) method, **it catches  *only* `ValidationError`**

```
if not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
    try:
        self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
    except ValidationError as exc:
        self._validated_data = {}
        self._errors = exc.detail
    else:
        self._errors = {}
```

At that time, DRF directly raises a `PermissionDenaid` exception and returns its own status code, which is customized by you

### Conclusion

**DRF Serializer ValidationError** never returns status code other that `HTTP 400` because it *catches **other sub validation error exceptions***(if any) and atlast raises a major `ValidationError` which return `HTTP 400` status code by it's design pattern

**Reference**:
[`is_valid()` source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L221)
[`ValidationError` class source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L142)

Answer (score 6):

yo bruh just create your own exception class and reraise it in serializer

```py
class ValidationError422(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY


class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ('id', 'name')

    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        try:
            return super(BusinessSerializer, self).is_valid(raise_exception)
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise ValidationError422(detail=e.detail)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround..bruh