# Django rest_framework custom error message

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a API endpoint where it will do input validation using rest_framework's `serializer.is_valid()` where it will return custom error message and response.

```
serializer = FormSerializer(data=data)
if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
    return Response({"Failure": "Error"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is it possible to populate validation errors without using the generic response provided by `raise_exception=True`? I am trying to avoid using the generic response as it will display all the validation errors if there are more than one error.

The response will be something like

```
return Response(
     {
          "Failure": "Error", 
          "Error_list": {"field1": "This field is required"}
     },
     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
)
```

Answer (score 13):

Create a *`Custom Exception`* class as,

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from rest_framework import status


class MyCustomExcpetion(PermissionDenied):
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_detail = "Custom Exception Message"
    default_code = 'invalid'

    def __init__(self, detail, status_code=None):
        self.detail = detail
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
```

Why I'm inherrited from **`PermissionDenied`** exception class ??
see this SO post -- [Why DRF `ValidationError` always returns `400`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567740/8283848)

Then in your serializer, raise exceptions as,

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = SampleModel

    def validate_age(self, age):  # field level validation
        if age > 10:
            raise MyCustomExcpetion(detail={"Failure": "error"}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return age

    def validate(self, attrs): # object level validation
        if some_condition:
            raise MyCustomExcpetion(detail={"your": "exception", "some_other": "key"}, status_code=status.HTTP_410_GONE)
        return attrs
```

`age` and `name` are two fields of `SampleModel` class

Response will be like this

[image]

By using this method,
**1.** You can customize the JSON Response
**2.** You can return any status codes
**3.** You don't need to pass `True` in `serializer.is_valid()` method (This is not reccomended)

Comment: Is it possible to catch field validation error in the object level validation? I have more than 20 fields and wish to just capture the first field validation error in the object level validation.

Comment: According to my example, you will get the value of your field by `attrs['your_field']`. Then check specific validation by yourself. If validation fails, raise the CustomException

Comment: So it is not possible if I were using `name = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)` as my field validation and catch it in the object level validation?

Comment: In that case, it will raise an **`HTTP 400 Bad Request`** only if you are set `raise_exception=True` in **`is_valid()`** ->> (`is_valid(True)`)

Comment: @Clueless_Coder Is there any problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can write custom [error handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling):

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if response is not None:
        response.data['Failure'] = 'Error'

    return response
```

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes. It only add `"Failure": "Error", ` to response.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use one of the exception messages, eg NotFound.  See [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#notfound)

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound

class myview(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        raise NotFound("My text here")
```

That will return a 404 and change the response to your text

```
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
{
    "detail": "my text here"
}
```