# How to create a custom response for permission classes like IsAuthenticated in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

How can I create custom response for permission classes

The response now is:

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

The response I want:

```
{
  "status": 403,
  "message": "Authentication credentials were not provided",
  "response": {....}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django rest\_framework custom error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665260/django-rest-framework-custom-error-message)

Comment: Did you get a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) you would need to override the `.handle_exceptions` method in your View to customize the responses.

Shown [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) in the official docs is how to make a custom exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what the OP was facing, but a similar issue and I just want to post this as an option to someone else who had this issue.

I was facing this same issue and in my case, I had a custom authentication class, which was being used in my View. No matter what custom message I set in my Permission classes the response would always be `Authentication credentials not provided`

Here is the solution I found.

The default behavior of django permission classes while raising permission_denied is that it checks for

```
if request.authenticators and not request.successful_authenticator:
    raise exceptions.NotAuthenticated()  # <-- HERE
raise exceptions.PermissionDenied(detail=message, code=code)
```

You can see this in more detail in this [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7712)
In my case, I was not doing `return user, None` upon successful authentication. However all my use-cases were working fine, since I was setting `request.user`

As soon as I started using `return user, None` the custom permissions start working.